# how to start/stop windows services that have spaces in their names using c/c++

Tags: visual-c++, windows-services

I am trying to write a c/c++ application that start/stop any windows service of my system.

My application is working fine for services that have no spaces in between their name, but for service names that have space between them are not responding.

Following are the commands i am using for opening service:

```
SC_HANDLE serviceDbHandle = OpenSCManager(NULL,NULL,SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
SC_HANDLE serviceHandle = OpenService(serviceDbHandle,
                                      "My Service",
                                      SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
```

Here `"My Service"` - 2nd parameter is `LPCSTR` and its null termination is creating problem.

How can i start/stop services that have spaces in their name - any clue or suggestions would be helpful.

Iam using Visual studio 2005 in xp machine.

Thanks,

Anil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the service's internal name (which has no spaces), not the display name (which may).

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The name of the service to be opened. This is the name specified by the `lpServiceName` parameter of the `CreateService` function when the service object was created, **not the service display name that is shown by user interface applications to identify the service**.

Comment: hmm.. again its confusion, for some services exe names are not responding instead their display names are responding, its interesting, I have to continue my search for the reason, Maybe someone throw some light on it.

Comment: @Anil: Some services may have the same string for both internal name and display name.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with trying to start or stop a service from a windows `cmd` script if the service had a space in the name. I was able to work around this by writing a powershell `ps1` script and calling it from the `cmd` script. If you can run powershell script from C/C++, you could do something similar.

ps1 code

```
param([string[]] $Servers, [string] $Command)

$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter admin credentials"

foreach ($server in $servers)
{
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
        param([string] $cmd)
        sc.exe $cmd "My Service Name"
    } -ArgumentList $Command
}
```

where `$Command` is `start`, `stop`, `query`, etc.

This can be invoked from `cmd` script or probably in most programs, e.g. for C++, see here: [How should C++ execute the PowerShell command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55037943/how-should-c-execute-the-powershell-command)