# How to know the existing internal service name ( lpServiceName ) to stop it

Tags: c++, winapi

[The same problem but hasn't been solved yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354327/how-to-start-stop-windows-services-that-have-spaces-in-their-names-using-c-c)

I need to stop the remote desktop services in C++, but when calling this

```
SC_HANDLE WINAPI OpenService(
  _In_ SC_HANDLE hSCManager,
  _In_ LPCTSTR   lpServiceName, //"Remote Desktop Configuration" e.g.DisplayName 
  _In_ DWORD     dwDesiredAccess
);
```

About the lpServiceName  argument, When there is no space in this variable, it works fine,e.g. "WebClient". How do I know the corresponding correct name of "Remote Desktop Configuration" to successfully call the OpenService function

Comment: space is absolute legal symbol in service name. simply you confuse `service name` which you must use in call `OpenService` and `display name`

Comment: Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services.  Right-click the service and select Properties.  You'll see the "Service name", it is "SessionEnv".

Answer (score 3):

About the second parameter of [`OpenService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx) - *lpServiceName* :

> This is the name specified by the *lpServiceName* parameter of the
>   [CreateService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx)

But you are trying to use the *lpDisplayName* (3rd parameter of [CreateService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx)) as the `lpServiceName` parameter to [`OpenService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx) - this is an error. [`OpenService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx) works only with the *lpServiceName*
name.

> When there is no space in this variable, it works fine

A space character is absolutely legal in *lpServiceName* - no problem here. What you are really trying to say is it works fine
when *lpServiceName is equal to lpDisplayName*.