# How should C++ execute the PowerShell command?

Tags: c++, powershell

I want to execute the PowerShell command in C + + programming. I've edited the command statement that needs to be run.[PowerShell_CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWZIn.png)、[XML_File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBQx3.png)

Comment: How about something like `system("powershell 'echo \"hello from powershell\"'");`? I don't know how practical it is from anything more elaborate than that though...

Comment: I think it might be prudent to dump out a temporary ps1 file for something as complicated as what is shown in your image. Then @Blaze's answer could be adjusted to `system("powershell -f temp.ps1");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My assumption here is that you're trying to add `-auto` to the arguments. After reviewing the supplied image I would change the PowerShell code as well.

```
$task = Get-ScheduledTask "Test"
$items = @{}
if ($task.Actions.Execute -ne $null) {$items.Add('Execute', "$($task.Actions.Execute)")} 
$items.Add('Argument', "$($task.Actions.Arguments) -auto") 
if ($task.Actions.WorkingDirectory -ne $null) {$items.Add('WorkingDirectory',"$($task.Actions.WorkingDirectory)")} 
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction @items
$task.Actions = $action
Set-ScheduledTask -InputObject $task
```

Far simpler and easier to understand.

To run this in c++ you should dump the code to a temporary file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open("test.ps1");

    string newArg = "-auto";
    string powershell;
    powershell = "$task = Get-ScheduledTask \"Test\"\n";
    powershell += "$items = @{}\n";
    powershell += "if ($task.Actions.Execute -ne $null) {$items.Add('Execute', \"$($task.Actions.Execute)\")} \n";
    powershell += "$items.Add('Argument', \"$($task.Actions.Arguments) " + newArg + "\") \n"; // 'Argument' not a typo
    powershell += "if ($task.Actions.WorkingDirectory -ne $null) {$items.Add('WorkingDirectory',\"$($task.Actions.WorkingDirectory)\")} \n";
    powershell += "$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction @items\n";
    powershell += "$task.Actions = $action\n";
    powershell += "Set-ScheduledTask -InputObject $task\n";
    file << powershell << endl;
    file.close();

    system("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -F test.ps1");

    remove("test.ps1");
}
```

Comment: I call system () to execute when the script is disabled, I've changed the settings with the command--"Set-executionpolicy remotesigned", but I can do it when I right-click the PowerShell

Comment: So you're saying we can't use `-f file.ps1` ?

Comment: Yes, I do not know why I use System () to perform the prompt to disable, manually right-click to do it.

Comment: I uploaded another XML file diagram, want to increase the red part of the node, without PowerShell implementation,can you help me write the command statement to increase this node?

Comment: I've added a bypass for the ExecutionPolicy and made it copy over existing values if they exist. This should run and add any parameter you like in the `newArg` string.

Comment: thanks!I used it to do it -----system("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -F test.ps1");

Comment: Can we just run a command without creating a temporary `.ps` file?

Comment: @keineahnung2345You can by doing something like `system(("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"& {" + powershell + "}\"").c_str());` - Notice a string 'powershell' is used for the command and it's wrapped in `(string-goeshere).c_str();` to convert it to the necessary type.